# Tritium Decay and He-3, $n$ reaction

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, nuclear-engineering

I have two separate questions that I have simply not been able to find any answers to:

1. With regard to Tritium decay to He-3, I'm a bit confused as to why Tritium is unstable based on its $n$ to $p$ ratio. One would think that a single proton paired with two neutrons would be a "happy" nucleus.
2. When He-3 absorbs free neutrons, why is that neutron not incorporated into the nucleus to form He-4 over the ejection of a proton that is observed in this type of reaction?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The heuristic of neutrons to protons is just that - a heuristic. Now, that said, the mass difference between tritium and He-3 is a very small fraction of their binding energies. But, in our universe He-3 is slightly more stable.

Comment: For (2), you should look at an isobar diagram, say at https://nucldata.tunl.duke.edu/nucldata/figures/04figs/menu04.shtml - (He3+n) comes in 20.578MeV above the He-4 ground state, and the (T+p) level is 19.815MeV above the He-4 ground state. So, it provides an easy alternate exit path for the excited compound nucleus.